# Setting opactity of usercontrol embedded in a window through binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Window bound to a view model.  The Window contains several user controls. I would like to bind the opacity of one of the user controls to a property exposed in the windows view model.

Any ideas?

Here is a snippet of my XAML:

```
<Window xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:xxx.UI.Controls"  x:Class="xxx.xxx.UI.MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.UI"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.xxx.UI.ViewModels;assembly=xxx.xxx.UI.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="768" 
    d:DesignWidth="1366"
    Title="MCH Anywhere" 
    Icon="Images\Icons\app-icon.ico"
    Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"
    Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
    WindowState="Maximized">

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Controls:SoundControl x:Name="soundControl" Style="{StaticResource DeviceControlStyle}" Opacity="{Binding Path=SoundControlOpacity}" />
```

Here is a snippet of my window view model:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : IMainWindowViewModel, 
        INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.SoundControlOpacity = .2;  // binding does not work.
    }

    private double _soundControlOpacity;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the opacity of the Ultrasound control.
    /// </summary>
    public double SoundControlOpacity
    {
        get { return _soundControlOpacity; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _soundControlOpacity)
            {
                _soundControlOpacity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SoundControlOpacity");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Controls:SoundControl x:Name="soundControl" Style="{StaticResource DeviceControlStyle}" Opacity="{Binding DataContext.SoundControlOpacity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

Comment: Sorry for the response delay. I had to deal with Hurricane Irma. 
Your suggestion works nicely. Exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a property exposed from ancestor control, just like sTrenat explained, but I believe that there is a more maintanable way to achieve the same goal.

If I understand it right, your UserControls nested in your Window have their own ViewModels and their instances are being held in your WindowViewModel. In this case, I'd suggest you to create a class containing ControlOpacity property and derive from it in your UserControlViewModel. You sholud then bind it to opacity property of your UserControl in your UserControlView (not in WindowView). You can then change its value from UserControlViewModel or from WindowViewModel by assigning value to UserControlViewModel.ControlOpacity.

That way you don't break single responsibility rule and you have more flexible and maintanable solution to your problem (which you can easily reuse in another controls).